# SQL syntax error when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I use `MySQL` 5.6 command line client to create a simple database and I can create database yet to create my first table I have a syntax error that I cannot identify. Thanks for your help and sorry if there are English mispells it is not my first language.
Please find pasted the `SQL` syntax error:

```
mysql> USE SYLVAINTEST
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE students
    ->   (
->      studentid INT NOT NULL,
->      firstname VARCHAR,
->      lastname  VARCHAR,
->      dob       VARCHAR,
->      CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY (studentid)
->   );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>        lastname  VARCHAR,
>        dob       VARCHAR,
>        CONSTRAINT pk_students ' at line 4

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE students
->   (
->   studentid  INT  NOT NULL,
->   firstname  VARCHAR    ,
->   lastname  VARCHAR    ,
->   dob VARCHAR ,
->   CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY (studentid)
->   );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>       lastname  VARCHAR    ,
>       dob VARCHAR ,
>       CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY (' at line 4

Comment: Try including a length with `VARCHAR()` for one thing.  Also, if `dob` is for "date of birth", that should be a date not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify lenght for `VARCHAR()` in following:

```
CREATE TABLE students
    (
    studentid INT NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(40),
    lastname  VARCHAR(40),
    dob       VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY (studentid)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing length for VARCHAR datatypes

```
CREATE TABLE students
      (
     studentid INT NOT NULL,      firstname VARCHAR(100),      
     lastname  VARCHAR(100),
     dob  VARCHAR(20),
     CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY (studentid)
      );
```

Also make sure to use proper datetime datatype to store datatetime values

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works. 
I do not understand why for the last and first name I cannot set up varchar(40) for example to save space. Why are there any syntax problem with
 dob VARCHAR (20) ?
I am very glad that works but I do not understand why in fact
Thanks

Comment: you should use datetime datatype to store date values. Otherwise your data is varchar and no calculation can be done until it is converted to datetime